# Unpack class scope?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

Consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename Type>
struct Something
{
    template <typename OtherType> 
    static constexpr bool same()
    {return std::is_same<Type, OtherType>::value;}
};

template <class Type>
struct Example
{
    static_assert(Type::template same<double>(), "ERROR");
};

int main()
{
    Example<Something<double>> example;
    return 0;
}
```

The `static_assert` checks whether the passed type satisfy some condition by executing the `same()` function.

Now consider that one can pass multiple `Types` to `Example`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename Type>
struct Something
{
    template <typename OtherType> 
    static constexpr bool same()
    {return std::is_same<Type, OtherType>::value;}
};

template <class... Types>
struct Example
{
    static_assert(/* SOMETHING */, "ERROR");
};

int main()
{
    Example<Something<double>> example;
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a working syntax instead of `SOMETHING` to check whether the condition is verified on all types (without a bunch of helper functions: I know that can be done in this way but I wonder if there is another way (like using a simple unpacking somewhere...))

Comment: Really the only thing you can do with a parameter pack is unpack it as a set of parameters to a function.  So no, can't do that without a helper

Comment: @MooingDuck Sir, why not an answer?

Comment: @luk32: I had ambition for two sentences at the time, but not much more.  I've flushed out a full answer now.

Comment: check out the following, it might help http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=77063275dc772ae05e430272a2c9f444-ff683aff19d685e086e79e4ef634f9fb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really the only thing you can do with a parameter pack is unpack it as a set of parameters to a function. So no, can't do that without a helper.

If you allow helper functions, there's a thousand ways to do it.  The most obvious is some sort of `logical_and`

```
template<class first, class ...rest>
constexpr bool logical_and(first f, rest... r)
{return bool(f) && logical_and(std::forward<rest>(r)...));}
//                           ^unpack the rest recursively^

template<class last>
constexpr bool logical_and(last l)
{return bool(l);}

template <class... Types>
struct Example
{
    static_assert(logical_and(Something<double>::same<Types>()...), "ERROR");
    //                        ^unpack the results to the function^
};
```

This is completely untested, and probably doesn't compile as-is

Answer (score 0):

You can do without helper functions by simply specializing 
`template Example`.

If in the real world `Example` is a class that you
wouldn't want to specialize just for the sake of the variadic
`static_assert` then you can encapsulate the variadic `static_assert`
in its own template specializations and have your real world class
inherit the corresponding instantiation. Here is an illustration
that just specializes `Example`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename Type>
struct Something
{
    template <typename OtherType> 
    static constexpr bool same()
    {return std::is_same<Type, OtherType>::value;}
};

template<class ...Types>
struct Example;

template<>
struct Example<>{};

template<class T>
struct Example<T>
{
    static_assert(T::template same<double>(), "ERROR");
};

template<class First, class ...Rest>
struct Example<First,Rest...> : Example<Rest...>
{
    static_assert(First::template same<double>(), "ERROR");
};

int main()
{
    Example<Something<double>> example0; // OK
    Example<Something<double>,Something<double>> example1; // OK
    Example<Something<int>> example2; // Error
    Example<Something<double>,Something<int>> example3; // Error
    Example<Something<double>,Something<double>,Something<int>> example4; // Error
    Example<Something<double>,Something<int>,Something<double>> example5; // Error
    return 0;
}
```